# Should the typography tag and typesetting tag be merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don’t understand why there is a [typesetting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) tag that is distinct from a [typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) tag.

Is there any good reason for those to be separate?

If not, I would like to propose that they please be merged.

Comment: This was already done, so I’m marking it done.